# Java - control flow of application with environment variables

Tags: java

This is more of a general best practice question regarding environment variables and their uses in Java.

Let's say I have an web application (1) that uses web services to target another application (2). I want in pre-prod environments to keep this link as optional in the flow of the application: if application 2 is down, I want to target a mocked server, that always gives back an answer.
How do I do this the best way?

I was thinking I can use an environment variable like app1.usemockserver = false. When I know that app 2 is down, I can set app1.usemockserver = true, and with an IF in my code I can target the mock server, and not application 2.

Is it something wrong doing it this way? What alternatives could I use?

Comment: When you say 'environment variable' do you really mean 'system property'?  System properties seem like they would be more appropriate for this purpose than environment variables.

Comment: @aroth - I was talking more about os env variables. System properties would certainly mean restarting the application, right? It's not that it's a bad thing, but it would be nicer to have something on the fly at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what SMA answered, I think the best choice would be in fact using JMX. 
But, to have something fully automated, that falls back to a mocked web service, JMX could be used in conjuncture with a modified circuit-breaker, like in this framework:

[Spring in Practice - kite](https://github.com/williewheeler/kite)

So, when the circuit-breaker opens, it could just target the mocked web service.

Answer (score 2):

This one would be difficult using environment variable as JVM will pick up all environment variable that was defined when JVM was launched. Anything chnaging there after wont be picked up.

I would suggest you look at JMX and expose a bean which will set the boolean flag to switch from one environment to the other dynamically within existing JVM.

You could even expose RPC call to JVM to set/reset the boolean flag but i would prefer JMX.

Another way would be to have a load balancer service running on top of your service which will do hearbeat and once it doesn't hears from respective servcie, it switches over to the other.